# Contour integral $\int^\pi_{-\pi}(a-\cos\theta)^b\exp(c\cos\theta)d\theta$ assuming $a>1$, $b>0$, $c>0$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, contour-integration, hypergeometric-function

Under the condition $a>1$, $b>0$, $c>0$, is there any good function to express the following integral?
$$
\int^\pi_{-\pi}\left(a-\cos\theta\right)^b\exp\left(c\cos\theta\right)d\theta
$$
I guess some hypergeometric function can do this.

Comment: Substituting $x=\cos\theta$, the integral becomes $I(a,b,c)=2\int_{-1}^{1}(a-x)^{b}\exp{(c\,x)}\,\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The form you showed seems to have high compatibility with a function called Gegenbauer's Polynomial, and now I'm playing around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_{-\pi}^\pi(a-\cos\theta)^be^{c\cos\theta}~d\theta$

$=\int_{-\pi}^0(a-\cos\theta)^be^{c\cos\theta}~d\theta+\int_0^\pi(a-\cos\theta)^be^{c\cos\theta}~d\theta$

$=\int_\pi^0(a-\cos(-\theta))^be^{c\cos(-\theta)}~d(-\theta)+\int_0^\pi(a-\cos\theta)^be^{c\cos\theta}~d\theta$

$=\int_0^\pi(a-\cos\theta)^be^{c\cos\theta}~d\theta+\int_0^\pi(a-\cos\theta)^be^{c\cos\theta}~d\theta$

$=2\int_0^\pi(a-\cos\theta)^be^{c\cos\theta}~d\theta$

$=2\int_1^{-1}(a-x)^be^{cx}~d(\cos^{-1}x)$

$=2\int_{-1}^1\dfrac{(a-x)^be^{cx}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

$=2\int_0^2\dfrac{(a-(x-1))^be^{c(x-1)}}{\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}}d(x-1)$

$=2e^{-c}\int_0^2x^{-\frac{1}{2}}(2-x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}(a+1-x)^be^{cx}~dx$

$=2e^{-c}\int_0^1(2x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}(2-2x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}(a+1-2x)^be^{2cx}~d(2x)$

$=2(a+1)^be^{-c}\int_0^1x^{-\frac{1}{2}}(1-x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(1-\dfrac{2x}{a+1}\right)^be^{2cx}~dx$

$=2\pi(a+1)^be^{-c}~\Phi_1\left(\dfrac{1}{2},-b,1;\dfrac{2}{a+1},2c\right)$ (according to [About the confluent versions of Appell Hypergeometric Function and Lauricella Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812748))

Answer (score 1):

For natural values of *c*, it can be expressed in terms of [Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) as $\pi\Big[P\cdot I_0(c)-Q\cdot I_1(c)\Big]$

where *P* and *Q* are polynomials of degree *b* and $b-1$ in *a*, with factors depending on powers of *c*,

whose exponents are negative integers, no bigger than *b* in absolute value. This can be shown by

[writing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) $\cos x$ as $\dfrac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2$ , and then expanding using the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem). In general, many

integrals containing $f\Big(g(x)\Big)$, with *f* and *g* trigonometric, hyperbolic, or exponential functions, can

be expressed in a similar fashion. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But unfortunately, neither _b_ nor _c_ can be regarded to be an integer in this problem.

Comment: For $a=1$ we get an expression in terms of [regularized confluent hypergeometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function), which, for $b=\dfrac12$ , can further be simplified to one in terms of [error functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Comment: Thank you for further examination. Also, another simplification with $c=0$ is expressed by a Gauss hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1$.