# About the extensions from Confluent Hypergeometric Function of the Second Kind

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, hypergeometric-function

I know that $\int_0^\infty t^{a-1}(1+t)^{c-a-1}e^{-yt}~dt=\Gamma(a)U(a,c,y)$ , where $\text{Re}(a),\text{Re}(y)>0$ .

How about $\int_0^\infty t^{a-1}(1+t)^{c-a-1}(1+xt)^{-b}e^{-yt}~dt$ and $\int_0^\infty t^{a-1}(1+t)^{c-a-1}(1+x_1t)^{-b_1}\cdots(1+x_nt)^{-b_n}e^{-yt}~dt$ , where $\text{Re}(a),\text{Re}(y)>0$ ? Do some definitions in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbert_series can help us?

Comment: What are you trying for?  In any case the Laplace transform of t^c * Phi2(;;)  (Humbert's function) seems to resemble what you want: look at http://apps.nrbook.com/bateman/Vol1.pdf section 4.24 (5).  Or http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html   (without the exp(-yt).  Just as an aside any of the real line integrals of functions with a Taylor expansion and a factor of exp(-y*t) can be reduced too a Taylor series in t  sum(p_n(y)*t^n) where p_n is a polynomial of order n.

Comment: @rrogers I asked the $\int_0^1$ version before (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812748) and it had solved perfectly. Now I ask about the $\int_0^\infty$ version.

Comment: :I will give it a try; but it might be some time.  You might try adopting the argument that leads to Bateman Integral Transforms Volume 1, section 5.4 equation (9).  http://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/1/Volume%201.pdf    Its the complex domain form though; and the exp(yt) would have to be transformed on the coefficients (y) and such.

Comment: I did manage to do your 2 term (1+xx) equation with Reduce-algebra and it reflects the fact that we end up with summing sequences of HyperGeometric functions which _can_ be calculated and could be encoded recursively, but I am not sure anybody is interested.   The fundamental idea is to apply: http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.5.E3  to a fabricated hypergeometric representation of the product (1+x*t)....  .  For instance, see http://apps.nrbook.com/bateman/Vol3.pdf Page 268 19.11 (3) .   Reduce-algebra can be beat up to handle many problems of this type.

Comment: Instead of 16.5.E3 one can realize that $ int(e^{-t}*t^{a-1},0,inf)=\Gamma(a) $  Which actually proves 16.5.E3 .